# Getting the DataRow with max DateTime value from DataRow[]

Tags: c#-4.0, filter, datatable, max, datarow

```
DataTable dt = db.Execute("select statement...");
```

I have this datatable which contains some data with a status column and a date column.

from that data I filter to get only the rows that have a specific status

```
DataRow[] potentialRows = dt.Select("status = 1");
```

Now here's my question:

from this DataRow[] of potential rows I want to further filter it to get only one DataRow which contains the closest date to today

(e.g.: if I have two rows: one with a date of yesterday and one with a date of a week ago, I want the DataRow that has the date of yesterday)

I tried the following:

```
DataRow dr = potentialRows.Max(x => x["date"]) as DataRow;
```

but this doesn't seem to work so I must be missing something.

thank you for any comment or solution.

Comment: added my own answer/solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
dr = potentialRows.OfType<DataRow>().OrderBy(r => r["date"]).LastOrDefault<DataRow>();
```

ordering the array by the date field and grabbing the last element which holds the most current date.

Comment: Ok no problem. how would you suggest i edit my answer then? what should i write?